# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 10 y sizes: 1 Please provide data which shares the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a Keras model. Here my code

```
init_data = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0])
init_data = np.array(init_data,dtype="float").reshape(-1,1)

result_data = np.array([11.0])
result_data = np.array(result_data,dtype="float").reshape(-1,1)

stock_model = Sequential()
stock_model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(10,1), return_sequences=True))
stock_model.add(LSTM(5, activation="relu"))
return_sequences = True

stock_model.add(Dense(1))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01)

stock_model.summary()
stock_model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=sgd, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.mse])
stock_model.fit(init_data, result_data, epochs=100, verbose=1)
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 10
  y sizes: 1
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

I've tried a lot, but unfortunately haven't solved the problem. I've read the other questions referencing the same error, but I'm not really understanding what I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add batch dimension:

```
init_data = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0])
init_data = np.array(init_data,dtype="float").reshape(1,-1,1) # <= add dimension here

result_data = np.array([11.0])
result_data = np.array(result_data,dtype="float").reshape(1,-1,1) # <= add dimension here
```

EDIT:

For 2-dim data:

```
init_data = np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]])
init_data = init_data[..., tf.newaxis]
```

Comment: Thanks! And how does it work with an multidimensional array?

Comment: @mzwle sorry, dont understand your question. Tensorflow normally working with multidimensional arrays

Comment: When I use a multidimensional array, i.e. `np.array([[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0],[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0]])` Then interprets stock_model.fit(...) it as a record and not as two or more.

Comment: @mzwle `fit()` will interpret it as two sequences

Comment: What means this Warning? `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 10, 1) for input Tensor("lstm_input:0", shape=(None, 10, 1), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 20, 1).`

Comment: @mzwle remove this line: `init_data = np.array(init_data,dtype="float").reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: Now I have this Error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 10]`

Comment: And the warning is still there.